# ¿Qué significa la expresión "echar toda la carne al asador"?

Tags: definiciones, méxico

¿Qué significa la expresión  "echar toda la carne al asador"? Esta frase la he escuchado en México.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente es utilizada en México, se usa cuando una persona va a poner un esfuerzo mayor o bien posiblemente conlleve arriesgar algo con tal de lograr un objetivo, dando hasta lo último que pueda dar con tal de alcanzarlo. Por ejemplo:

Voy a echarle toda la carne al asador con tal de que la muchacha me diga que sí.

En este caso, sería que sin importar mucho los impedimentos que pudieran existir, la persona hará su máximo esfuerzo para que le digan que sí, en el caso del ejemplo, posiblemente incluiría algo como llevar a cenar a la muchacha, comprarle un obsequio o en casos graves o extremos contratar un "Mariachi" o algo por el estilo.

También es intercambiable por "Echarle los kilos". Y en ocasiones con un significado económico se intercambia por "Echar la casa por la ventana", por ejemplo:

Está echando la casa por la ventana con tal de que prospere su negocio.

En este caso pudiera intercambiarse por: Está echando toda la carne al asador... Sin embargo en este sentido es generalmente usado para hablar de una inversión económica con tal de lograr el objetivo, mientras que "la carne al asador" puede referirse a arriesgar o esforzarse.

Saludos

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, nos da gusto tenerte por aquí. ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! También en España se usa, con el mismo significado. :)

Comment: Yo diría que en España se usa más en la forma "poner toda la carne en el asador". De hecho, es [la que indica la RAE en el diccionario](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=carne)

Comment: En Chile se usa la expresión "Echar toda la carne a la parrilla", con el mismo significado expresado por @GabrielG

Comment: En Argentina significa basicamente lo mismo (invertir todo lo que tenes para lograr un objetivo), aunque "echar la casa por la ventana" tiene un significado diferente (lo definiria algo asi como 'una fiesta como si no hubiera mañana')

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina el significado es el mismo, dar todo lo que uno tiene para dar en determinado objetivo, dar todo.